# ObjectAtIndex method of an NSMutableArray Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I'm using an NSMUtableArray to store some objects I created. but when I write [myArray objectAtIndex:i] where i is a valid index for that particvular array one of two thing happens: if I'm using the simulator to run the app everything works ok...If I run the app on my Iphone the app crashes...any clues why is it crashing?

Comment: please post the actual code it will help

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you crash?

Comment: 1) when in the device, the index *isn't* actually good.  2) either the array or the object within it has been released (or corrupted) - break at that point in the debugger and check things out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely it is a memory management issue. Are you abiding by rules set out in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)? Try:

- revising the memory management rules, make sure you are not using any objects that you don't own, make sure you are retaining objects you want to keep (and releasing them appropriately afterwards);
- running your code through the static analyser;
- enabling NSZombies;
- running your app through Leaks.

You have not given us anywhere near enough information for us to give you a reliable, straightforward answer.